# validate clipboard when applicationWillEnterForeground happens (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app that will allow to copy images to an image view from a safari search and the when I reopen the app and if I am in a specific view (the picture below) I need to validate if the clipboard is not empty I want to enable a paste button.
[image]

I would like to know how can I do this in swift.

Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for images on the clipboard like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image != nil {
        pasteButton.enabled = true
    } 
    else {
        pasteButton.enabled = false
    }
}
```

If you want to use the event, you can do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
    selector: Selector("updatePasteButton"), 
    name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, 
    object: nil)
}

func updatePasteButton() {
    if UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image != nil {
        pasteButton.enabled = true
    } 
    else {
        pasteButton.enabled = false
    }
}
```

updatePasteButton() will get called every time the event happens.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, but the question where can I put that, my point is when the application comes back to execution, the only event that I think I control is the application one mentioned in the question, is any way to do the same thing but at the view level?  Or putting the question in a different way; can I identity in that method the current view displayed?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please have a look and let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks very very much. that is what I was looking for.